# UIApplication sharedapplication openURL not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, uiapplication, openurl

I have this method

```
- (IBAction)facebookButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"fb hit");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
}
```

and I don't understand why safari doesnt open the link. I get the 'fb hit' logged, so the method is being called, but it doesnt open the link in Safari, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it without the encoding like this.

```
- (IBAction)facebookButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"fb hit");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge"]];
}
```

Also try changing the URL to `http://www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge`

Comment: It is kind of strange, their seems to be no problem with the code

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge" ]];  Not working

Comment: Have you found any solution for opening www.facebook.com

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)facebookButtonPress:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"fb hit");
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge"]];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I dont know what was wrong but it's working now

Comment: The `http://` was missing. In general the additional brackets with the encoding is not a bad thing to do. But in case of this constant URL it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was in extra "/" at the end.

doesn't work:
`@"http://www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge/"`

works fine:
`@"http://www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge"`